# Laravel : How to check if table exists in database on view file

Tags: php, laravel

I have an index file which is view file. In this view, I want to show the records of `temptable` **if only that table already exists** and if it does not exist yet, then I don't show anything. For your information, this `temptable` can only be created only after the user **submit form**. So, if a user submit a student form, **Laravel will create a database table with columns based on the form submitted**. I need to check if the table already exists in the view to determine to show or not to show the records. I have seen the solutions out there (like with Schema, etc) but I don't think it will work for a view file. Is there any way I could check if database table exists on view file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Schema's [`hasTable()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#checking-for-table-column-existence) method :

```
@if(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema::hasTable('temptable')) 
   // Your code
@endif
```